# Accessing a symbolic link on a Mac, when the directory is shared and mapped to a Windows drive letter

Tags: mac, symbolic-link

The symbolic link points to an external hard drive on the Mac.

When I access the symbolic link from the Windows machine, I get an access denied error.

What do I need to do so that I can get to the external hard drive attached to my Mac through the symbolic link when I map it to my Windows machine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows doesn't access symlinks how *nix and Mac do, to get around this you'll need to create a symlink using [MKLINK](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/using-symlinks-in-windows-vista/)

```
MKLINK [[/D] | [/H] | [/J]] Link Target

        /D      Creates a directory symbolic link.  Default is a file
                symbolic link.
        /H      Creates a hard link instead of a symbolic link.
        /J      Creates a Directory Junction.
        Link    specifies the new symbolic link name.
        Target  specifies the path (relative or absolute) that the new link
                refers to.
```